# How do i force my user to make a selection from ListViewer?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

My problem is that even though a user doesnt make a selection in the listViewer, my program still creates an object with reference "null". How can i remove the object, or even better, how do i make it unable to proceed if a selection is not made?

The program works great as long as i select an item in the list. Let me know if you need more info or code!

EDIT: Obviously i provided way to little info on my problem. Lets say ListView selections provides "Driver1". If i click "Book" button , the new booking gets Driver1 as a driver. However, if i just enter "Book" button, i get "null" as a driver

```
 int input = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

    TaxiSystem.createBooking(dest.getText(), pass.getText(), name.getText(),input);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSelectedIndex()` will return `-1` if nothing is selected (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedIndexProperty)). So you can do

```
int input = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

if (index >=0) {
    TaxiSystem.createBooking(dest.getText(), pass.getText(), name.getText(),input);   
}
```

Alternatively, it might be more convenient to use `getSelectedItem()` (depending on what your `createBooking` method is doing). That method will return `null` if nothing is selected:

```
MyDataType item = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

if (item != null) {
    // ...
}
```

where `MyDataType` is the data type for your `ListView`.